# Asus Eee PC 1001PX netbook: best OS for battery life?

Tags: operating-systems, netbook, battery-life

I am looking for an OS to replace Windows XP Home edition on my **Asus Eee PC 1001PX** netbook.
**The most critical issue for me is battery life.**

I would like to use Ubuntu Netbook Edition, but heard that it is a battery eater.
A friend of mine recommended Puppy Linux, he said that it is lightweight and definitely will run longer than Windows XP.

What is the most energy-saving OS for this netbook?  .
Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

I run an Eee PC 1000H , and use Ubuntu desktop,, for power saving I use a program called Jupiter its very similar to Asus SHE control

and very easy to install

http://www.jupiterapplet.org/index.html

http://www.webupd8.org/2010/07/jupiter-ubuntu-ppa-hardware-and-power.html

Answer (score 0):

You should try Jolicloud which can tested via [Chrome AppStore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nfakdllpdfjjbfommlcnfkedmbigkfdo)